# Anybody using Alpha anywhere and successfully develop mobile application that can work offline and online?

Tags: phonegap

Mobile application cannot work in offline, the list works well in online,Auto sync the data in the list to the server to ease the user when online but, while offline, I cannot open the page to display the list not to mention the list detail view.

by referring  to all the videos related , documentation about method to open ux in PhoneGap the video to persist the data in file system /local storage , restore everything to the list from the data in local storage/FS, all checked but none works.

Hope any alphaholics will help me out,

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First off you must tell the list and the UX to store/restore the list data.
To persist the list to local storage (its a tickbox in List Properties > Persist data to Local Storage ) 
you must tell the UX component to restore it (UX > Properties > Restore data in List controls from Local Storage)

**Phonegap**
In phonegap your application can load even when there is no connection, this is because all the lists have a pre-compiled version stored in the apk. Note: the list will have the data that was on your development machine by default so you need to make sure you set the connection strings etc to return data that end users should see.

**HTML**
If you user is loading the UX via a a5w page, even one pinned to their home screen, then they must have connection when they open the a5w page, then they can go offline.
We have a customer facing shop that works like this and it is quite effective.

Comment: That is great Jon!! Do you use separate UX and call them in embedded object? I am sure I have checked all the required properties as in the doc and video but don't know where I miss. I will keep sharing update!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, didnt have enough reputation to reply.

Comment: We have not had great success using embedded UX and try to keep all the controls in a single UX where possible.

Comment: I guess I will have to go with that. Embedded object in Offline seems "unstable" or require more setting that is hidden from my eye and I am running out of time..After you, I am convinced to go on 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

To make my life easier, I just realized there is a "mobile application disconnected sample" template option when we want to create a new UX component. All the properties already set for disconnected use but the problem is user must go to the page first before they can go offline. There must be workaround but, saving and keeping the edit while offline is a great achievement. Yess,you never want to lose the edit while you are offline, or accidentally cleared the device cache!!

Comment: This sample work good but If we exit our application and go offline, another question mark  ""?"" , I cannot go to the list in embedded object. It wont let me see the list.

Comment: I have brought all my UX in 1 page UX component. currently there are no big issues and the recalculating is no longer there for now.